# Problem in using tcolorbox with c++ #if #endif directives

Tags: tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox` to highlight a `c++` code in my document. Could someone shed light on why it the compiler complains about the `#if` directive? The error I get is:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $ \PY{c+cp}{\PYZsh{}if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5}
```

When I comment the directives everything works fine. The following is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}

\newtcblisting{cppcode}[1][]{
  listing engine=minted,
  breakable,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=black!70,
  listing only,
  minted style=colorful,
  minted language=c++,
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
  left=5mm,enhanced,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\begin{document}

\begin{cppcode}[]
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    streamLine->SetInput( sgrid );
    streamLine->SetSource( seeds->GetOutput() );
#else   
    streamLine->SetInputData( sgrid );
    streamLine->SetSourceConnection( seeds->GetOutputPort() );
#endif
\end{cppcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `texcl=true` option confuses Pygments. If I remove it, the document compiles.

Comment: @egreg I was writing an answer while you wrote your comment. Do you want to provide the answer? I can delete mine.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Don't worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you set `texcl` to `true` and this causes problems (in the first line with the `#` character the underscores in `VTK_MAJOR_VERSION` are interpreted as the math-mode subscript character and since they appear in text mode, the error is triggered).

You have several possible solutions:

1. Either remove the option globally  or disable it locally:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

   \usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}

   \usepackage{tcolorbox}
   \tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}

   \newtcblisting{cppcode}[1][]{
     listing engine=minted,
     breakable,
     colback=bg,
     colframe=black!70,
     listing only,
     minted style=colorful,
     minted language=c++,
     minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
     left=5mm,enhanced,
     overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
               rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
   }
   \definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{cppcode}[texcl=false]
   #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
       streamLine->SetInput( sgrid );
       streamLine->SetSource( seeds->GetOutput() );
   #else   
       streamLine->SetInputData( sgrid );
       streamLine->SetSourceConnection( seeds->GetOutputPort() );
   #endif
   \end{cppcode}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Escape the underscore so it's not interpreted as the math-mode character for subscripts:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

   \usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}

   \usepackage{tcolorbox}
   \tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}

   \newtcblisting{cppcode}[1][]{
     listing engine=minted,
     breakable,
     colback=bg,
     colframe=black!70,
     listing only,
     minted style=colorful,
     minted language=c++,
     minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
     left=5mm,enhanced,
     overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
               rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}
   }
   \definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{cppcode}[]
   #if VTK\_MAJOR\_VERSION <= 5
       streamLine->SetInput( sgrid );
       streamLine->SetSource( seeds->GetOutput() );
   #else   
       streamLine->SetInputData( sgrid );
       streamLine->SetSourceConnection( seeds->GetOutputPort() );
   #endif
   \end{cppcode}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: Thanks. I tried to define `texcl` globally by `minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},` along with disabling it locally`\begin{cppcode}[texcl=false]` but it did not work. When I do it both locally and globally it works fine. How would you enable it globally but locally disable it?

Comment: @Ahm exactly as you are doing (I had a typo in my answer, but nowe I've corrected it). If you compile my (updated) answer *as is*, doesn't it work for you? If not, what kind of error(s) do you get?

Comment: @Ahm I updated my answer with another possible solution.